# Reading a text file from directory

Tags: php, html

I'm beginner in html and php. I trying to create a script that will open the directory, display all text files, open each of them for editing and save the changes to a file (all the script operation will be transferred to the html form). Unfortunately, after opening the directory and viewing the files, I have trouble reading their contents. Could someone tell me what I doing wrong ?
Thank for help

```
<?php 

$path = "books/";
$books = opendir($path);                                     
while (($book = readdir($books)) !== false)                     
{
    echo $book;
    foreach (glob("*.txt") as $readfile)
    {
        $readFile = fopen($book, "r") or die("Permission error");
        echo fread($readFile, filesize($book));
        fclose($readFile);
    }
    
}
closedir();
?>
```

Server response:
...Atlas_chmur.txtDiuna.txt

I used the loop so that only .txt files were opened. Currently I have this:

```
<?php 

$path = "books/";
$books = opendir($path);                                     
while (($book = readdir($books)) !== false)                     
{
    echo $book;
    
    $readFile = fopen($book, "r") or die("Permission error");
    echo fread($readFile, filesize($book));
    fclose($readFile);   
    
}
closedir();
?>
```

Now I'm getting an error when trying to read the files.
Server response:
. Warning: fopen (.): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ BooksEditorForm \ index.php on line 9 Permission error

Comment: Why do you have `foreach (glob("*.txt") as $readfile)` in this?  Try and remove that loop altogether as it seems to find the file, you just need the `fopen` (although there are shorter ways of doing this).

Comment: By why do you have two nested loops there? Is this supposed to read from multiple _folders_ contained in `books`, or what exactly?

Comment: Please don’t put extended code snippets in comments, that is hard to read. Edit your question, and insert the properly formatted code there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$path = "blog/";
$books = opendir($path);
while (($book = readdir($books)) !== false)
{
    if( substr($book, -4) === ".txt" )
    {
        $filePath = $path.$book;
        $readFile = fopen($filePath, "r") or die("Permission error");
        echo fread($readFile, filesize($filePath));
        fclose($readFile);
    }

}
closedir();
```

Let me explain it...

First, occasions where you need loop inside a loop are quite rare so if your code has them, analyze it because there's a big possibility that problem can be solved differently and more efficient.

Code: value of $book is string that contains filename so simple use of substr() function to check last 4 characters will tell us is it of "*.txt" format.
Other thing that is changed is filepath; $book contains it's name but your script is looking for a file from its own perspective so file path should be containing folder + filename.

And there's no need for closing PHP tags at the end unless you have something else following it that is not PHP (like HTML).

Comment: Great, it worked. Thank you very much. I just need to separate the content of the files so that it is not displayed in one string, but I thin i'll be able to deal with it already.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code. It's working well.try this code

```
 $files = scandir('books/');
        if(count($files) > 0) {
            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {            
                echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';
                // to read files data
                $readFileVar = fopen ($value, "r");
                 while ($filedata = fgets($readFileVar)) { 
                     print_r($filedata);
                  }
            }
        }
```